# R package installation from source using multiple cores

Tags: r, g++

I am installing some R packages from source like (RQuantlib) package installation is taking about ten minutes. Is possible to use multiple cores during compilation?

Answer (score 5):

The C++ code in RQuantLib is famously taxing -- a lot of templates, a lot of Boost, a lot of QuantLib headers.

To answer your question, set

```
 $ export MAKE="make -j8"
```

in the shell before calling `R CMD INSTALL`.  This is documented in the 'R Administration and Installation' manual.

I do something more and deploy [ccache](https://ccache.samba.org/) which caches compilation results. So for unchanged files the gains can be tremendous.  Use it by setting the compiler eg

```
  CC="ccache gcc"
  CXX="ccache g++"
```

in `~/.R/Makeconf`.

Comment: I am in windows. Is there a way to do these in windows environment?

Comment: Sure. It still uses `make`.  But it is more painful to find / set `$HOME` so that the file is found.  You may need to look at a few existing questions on setting environment variables in Windows -- you can also do that outside of R.  As for `ccache`, I am not sure. I only use it on Linux and I know OS X has it.

Comment: Setting `Sys.setenv(MAKE = "make -j8")` now appears to result in an error `sh: 1: make -j8: not found` when used with `install.packages()`.

Comment: That is possible _as far as R is concerned_ but it remains valid for other projects. Maybe it has to be split over `MAKE` and `MAKEFLAGS`.  See the [R Installation and Administration](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html) for details---R can for example use multiple cpus when installing packages in parallel. That use is governed by `options(Ncpus=4)` (or another number) which I use along with `ccache`.